# Default _output.yml

Tags: r, r-markdown

I can set the output format for all RMarkdown files in a directory by [putting a `_output.yml` file in that directory](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/bookdown-project.html#output.yml). Is there a way of making such a file apply more broadly, e.g. to all RMarkdown files within a git repository? An R project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't quite solve the original problem but you can specify the YAML file that is to be used explicitly, so one could e.g. put a `_output.yml` at `~` and then have `Rmd` files contain the following header section:

```
---
output_yaml:
  - ~/_output.yml
  - _output.yml
---
```

which will use the "global" file if that exists and whatever is contained in the same folder as the `Rmd` file if that exists.